# Enable $_GET for one controller

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery, get

I am using jquery ajax with CI and when ajax makes a request it goes to

http://localhost/ci_2/index.php/path/controller/method?_=1297364139171

CI loads my default controller, not the one in the url, if anything i thought it would show 404 error. Is there any way to enable the path above to load the correct controller and not my default one.

I want to keep the timestamp in the query string for browser page cache reasons.

Im a bit confused as I thought you could use `$this->input-get()`?

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you do not need to do this to prevent caching as jquery includes a parameter in their ajax helper function to manually prevent caching...

[image]

Secondly if you are wanting to store the timestamp you are sending ( not *solely* for caching reasons ), just use codeigniter's built in uri structure and pass it as the last uri segment, placing it as the first argument of your `method`.

http://localhost/ci_2/index.php/path/controller/method/1297364139171

will hit

```
method($timestamp) {
    echo $timestamp;  //will print '1297364139171'
}
```